# Trying to merge two string array based on comparision

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my class :

```
public class Regions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string[] ParentName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have 2 list of above regions class like below containing some data:

```
var region1 = new Regions();
var region2 = new Regions();
```

Now **ParentName** contains data like below for **region1** :

```
[0] : Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3
[1] : Xxx.mp3
[2] : kkk.mp3
[3] : ppp.mp3,zzz.mp3,rrr.mp3,ddd.mp3
```

Now **ParentName** contains data like below for **region2** :

```
[0] : Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3,lmn.mp3
[1] : rrr.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3
```

Now I am trying to merge ParentName of region2 in to region1 if any part of region1 is matching with region2 after splitting records by comma like below :

```
[0] : Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3,lmn.mp3
[1] : Xxx.mp3
[2] : kkk.mp3
[3] : ppp.mp3,zzz.mp3,rrr.mp3,ddd.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3
```

Now in above expected output, *Abc.mp3 and Pqr.Mp3(Region1 and Region2) is matching only Lmn.mp3 is not matching so it will be appended at the end of Region1*.

For the last record from region1 and region2, *rrr.mp3 is matching(single match is also enough) so non matching record from region2 i.e ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3 will be appended at the end of region1*.

**Output I am getting in Region1:**

```
[0] : Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3
[1] : Xxx.mp3
[2] : kkk.mp3
[3] : ppp.mp3,zzz.mp3,rrr.mp3,ddd.mp3
[4] : Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3,lmn.mp3
[3] : rrr.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3
```

**Code :**

```
region1.ParentName = region1.ParentName.Concat(region2.ParentName).Distinct().ToArray();


public static T[] Concat<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)
        {
            if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
            if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
            int oldLen = x.Length;
            Array.Resize<T>(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
            Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
            return x;
        }
```

Comment: See left outer Join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @jdweng :Sorry but i dont think joining would gonna help me in this case

Comment: @Learning, are you sure your expected output is right? shouldn't be second line: `"Xxx.mp3,rrr.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3"`?

Comment: @RomaDoskoch But how rrr.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3 will come with xxx.mp3 as xxx.mp3 is not in region2.What i want is existing records in region1 should remain as it is (unmatch from region1 and region2).Only matching records region1 and region2 should be merged

Comment: @Learning, so, you want to merge lines from region2 to region1 with values that are in both regions and they should be distinct?

Comment: @RomaDoskoch:Yes even part of string matching from region1 and region2 should be merged after spliiting with comma .At the end region.parentname should contains distinct records..

Comment: What does the numbers in square brackets represents?

Comment: @jdweng : It is just an index number like how we get records in list or array.So that is just a position

Comment: Then don't you have var region1 = new List<List<Regions>>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if your names contain duplicates and how they should be handled, but here is the LINQ solution which produces the desired result with the specified inputs:

```
var e2Sets = region2.ParentName.Select(e2 => e2.Split(',')).ToList();
var result =
    from e1 in region1.ParentName
    let e1Set = e1.Split(',')
    let e2AppendSet = (
       from e2Set in e2Sets
       where e1Set.Intersect(e2Set).Any()
       from e2New in e2Set.Except(e1Set)
       select e2New
    ).Distinct()
    select string.Join(",", e1Set.Concat(e2AppendSet));
```

`result.ToArray()` will give you the desired new `region1.ParentName`.

**How it works:**

Since we basically need Cartesian product of the two input sequences, we start by preparing a list of the arrays of split strings of the second sequence, in order to avoid multiple `string.Split` inside the inner loop.

The for each element of the first sequence, we split it to array of strings, the for each split array in the second sequence which has a match (determined with [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) method) we select the unmatched strings using the [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then we flatten all the unmatched strings, apply [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the potential duplicates, concatenate the two sets and use `string.Join` to produce the new comma delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split()` method to get parts of string and find matches and `Join()` method to get final string:

```
private static void Merge(Regions region, Regions region2)
{
    List<List<string>> splittedLists = region.ParentName.Select(p => p.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()).ToList();
    List<List<string>> splittedLists2 = region2.ParentName.Select(p => p.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()).ToList();
    List<string> res = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in splittedLists)
    {
        bool wasMatch = false;           
        foreach (var s in item)
        {
            bool contains = false;
            foreach (var s2 in splittedLists2.Where(s2 => s2.Contains(s)))
            {
                wasMatch = true;
                contains = true;
                res.Add(string.Join(",", item.Concat(s2).Distinct()));
            }    
            if (contains)
            {
                contains = false;
                break;
            }
        }    
        if (!wasMatch)
        {
            res.Add(string.Join(",", item));
        }
    }    
    region.ParentName = res.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
public static void Merge(Regions first, Regions second)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(first, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (ReferenceEquals(second, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    first.ParentName = first.ParentName.Merge(second.ParentName).ToArray();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Merge(this IEnumerable<string> first, IEnumerable<string> second)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(first, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (ReferenceEquals(second, null))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    foreach (var f in first)
    {
        yield return f.Merge(second, ',');
    }
}

private static string Merge(this string first, IEnumerable<string> second, char separator)
{
    Debug.Assert(first != null);
    Debug.Assert(second != null);

    var firstSplitted = first.Split(separator);

    foreach (var s in second)
    {
        var sSplitted = s.Split(separator);

        if (firstSplitted.Intersect(sSplitted).Any())
            return string.Join(separator.ToString(), firstSplitted.Union(sSplitted));
    }

    return first;
}
```

Note that this will merge on the first match it finds; if duplicate values exist, it will only merge the first time the match is encountered.

The secret here is divide and conquer. If you are having trouble implementing a certain logic, then break it down into simpler steps and implement a method for each baby step. Once its working, if you really need to, you can refactor your code to make it more concise or performant.

If you run this:

```
var first = new Regions();
var second = new Regions();
first.ParentName = new[] { "Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3", "Xxx.mp3", "kkk.mp3", "ppp.mp3,zzz.mp3,rrr.mp3,ddd.mp3" };
second.ParentName = new[] { "Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3,lmn.mp3", "rrr.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3" };
Merge(first, second);
```

You will get the expected result. `first.ParentName` will be:

```
[0]: "Abc.mp3,Pqr.mp3,lmn.mp3"
[1]: "Xxx.mp3"
[2]: "kkk.mp3"
[3]: "ppp.mp3,zzz.mp3,rrr.mp3,ddd.mp3,ggg.mp3,yyy.mp3"
```

Comment: Actually i was thinking something like : Compare records from 2 array after splitting by comma and if any part of string matches then take records with highest count.For Eg : if i talk about first record then Abc.mp3 is matching so count from region2 is higher then take records from region2 in to region1.Something like this.Just a thought